# Refresh Apex not working on Lightning Record Form Save

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, refreshapex

I'm not able to understand how refreshApex works in LWC.

Here is what i'm trying to achieve:

On a web component show -

- Show most recent 10 records of Account
- a form (I used a lightning record form for creating new records , this comes with a save
  button which creates a new Account record and also refreshes the most
  recent view

This is the HTML code:

```
<template>
 <lightning-card title="Recent Accounts" icon-name="standard:account">
    <lightning-datatable data={accounts} columns={columns} hide-checkbox-column="true" key-field="Id"></lightning-datatable>
</lightning-card>
<lightning-card title="Create New Account">
    <lightning-record-form 
        object-api-name="Account"
        fields={fields}
        onsuccess={handleSuccess}>
    </lightning-record-form>
</lightning-card> 
</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement , wire , track} from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent'
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex'
import getAccRecs from '@salesforce/apex/GetRecentAccounts.getRecentAccs'
import NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Name'
import INDUSTRY_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Industry'

/* eslint-disable no-console */

export default class refreshApexComp extends LightningElement {

    wiredRslt;
    @track fields = [NAME_FIELD,INDUSTRY_FIELD];
    @track accounts;
    @track columns = [
        {
            label : 'Name',
            fieldName : 'Name',
            type : 'text',
            sortable : false
        },
        {
            label : 'Industry',
            fieldName : 'Industry',
            type : 'text',
            sortable : false
        }
    ];

    @wire(getAccRecs) wiredCallbackResult(result){
        this.wiredRslt = result.data;
        if(result.data){
            this.accounts = result.data
        }
    }

    handleSuccess(event){
        const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
            title : "Account created successfully",
            message : "Record Id " + event.detail.id,
            variant : "Success"
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(evt);

        refreshApex(this.wiredRslt); 

    }


}
```

Can someone tell me what am i missing here / doing in a wrong manner?

EDIT:
I tried wiring the apex method to a property instead of a function and then use refreshApex on the same and it worked fine. This is the HTML and JS code.

```
<template>
<lightning-card title="Recent Accounts" icon-name="standard:account">
    <lightning-datatable data={accounts.data} columns={columns} hide-checkbox-column="true" key-field="Id"></lightning-datatable>
</lightning-card>
<lightning-card title="Create New Account">
    <lightning-record-form 
        object-api-name="Account"
        fields={fields}
        onsuccess={handleSuccess}>
    </lightning-record-form>
</lightning-card> 
</template>

export default class refreshApexComp extends LightningElement {

    wiredRslt;
    @track fields = [NAME_FIELD,INDUSTRY_FIELD];
    @track accounts;
    @track columns = [
        {
            label : 'Name',
            fieldName : 'Name',
            type : 'text',
            sortable : false
        },
        {
            label : 'Industry',
            fieldName : 'Industry',
            type : 'text',
            sortable : false
        }
    ];

    @wire(getAccRecs) accounts;

    handleSuccess(event){
        const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
            title : "Account created successfully",
            message : "Record Id " + event.detail.id,
            variant : "Success"
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(evt);

        refreshApex(this.accounts); 

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is at below line:

`this.wiredRslt = result.data;`

Change it with this line below in order to make it work:

`this.wiredRslt = result;`

Comment: This one worked for me. Thanks!